# Reading Data (Numbers) from a Website

Tags: java, http

i would like to create an excel file with data from a website. In my inputstream i find something from the page but not the things i am looking for.

This is the website i want the data from: https://www.finanzen.net/bilanz_guv/adidas
As an Example i would like a System.out.println  that returns the earning per share ( in german: Ergebnis je Aktie" ) from the years 2011 to 2017 so it would be the following numbers:
3,20    2,51    3,76    2,35    3,30    5,08    6,69

What i have managed till now:

```
URL u = new URL("https://www.finanzen.net/bilanz_guv/adidas");
InputStream in = u.openStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    result.append(line);
}
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

But the result String does not contain any of the searched numbers.
It does contain the first line of the pages soucecode so as if i clicked on show the soucecode of the webpage in my browser.

As i have not much knowledge about programming keep the answeres simple :-)

Thanks

Comment: You are looking for a HTML Parser.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Comment: I would use [1]: https://jsoup.org. To parse the HTML into searchable objects, then you can find the id, name etc of the div you want, then retrieve the data.